# Angular 1 cli has multiple errors while making a new app

Tags: angularjs

I've just recently installed angular 1 cli and uninstalled it, today when I installed it again I get the following errors during 'ng new' execution and I can't even build/serve it, check below this code for the build/serve errors.

```
> ng-core-addons@0.0.9 postinstall C:\Users\pauld\Desktop\poop\node_modules\ng-core-addons
    > node ./node_modules/fs-concatenate -i content -o snippets.js

    module.js:472
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\pauld\Desktop\poop\node_modules\ng-core-addons\node_modules\fs-concatenate'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
        at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
        at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
        at bootstrap_node.js:535:3


npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN karma-jasmine@0.3.8 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-mocha-reporter@0.3.2 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN angularApp@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN angularApp@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN angularApp@0.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ng-core-addons@0.0.9 postinstall: `node ./node_modules/fs-concatenate -i content -o snippets.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ng-core-addons@0.0.9 postinstall script 'node ./node_modules/fs-concatenate -i content -o snippets.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ng-core-addons package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./node_modules/fs-concatenate -i content -o snippets.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ng-core-addons
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ng-core-addons
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pauld\Desktop\poop\npm-debug.log
```

When I try to serve/build I get the following, I tried to install karma package globally but didn't work either.
I even tried installing jasmine something, didn't work.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'karma'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pauld\Desktop\poop\node_modules\ngcli-task-runner\index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
[8:09:58 PM UTC] ERR! module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'karma'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pauld\Desktop\poop\node_modules\ngcli-task-runner\index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
 ×
```

Comment: Have you solved it? I had to install locally karma, jasmine-core, fs-concatenate and ng-core-addons (in this order). Building and serving seems to work fine (consider also this [issue](https://github.com/ngCli/ng-cli/issues/14)) but on testing it encounters some problem with relative path to karma.conf.js.

Comment: I have, yes. Removed all global dependencies/local, reinstall nodejs.

Comment: I have the same issue .

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Angular Cli to the latest version. Update the angular-cli package installed globally in your system, using below commands:

```
    npm uninstall -g angular-cli
    npm cache clean or npm cache verify (if npm > 5)
    npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

It will be fixed after the upgrade.